# Read first line of a command's output. Command connects me to a remote terminal

Tags: ssh, zsh

### Part 1

Say I have a command `my_command` that outputs multiple lines.

I would like to capture the first line of `my_command`'s output as soon as it's ready in a script, while keeping `my_command` running.

I thought something like this would work:

```
# Get a code that `my_command` prints in its first line
parsed_first_line=`my_command | grep -oEe '[0-9]+'` 
echo 'Here is the first line ' $parsed_first_line
```

but it doesn't. The echo statement is only reached only once `my_command` has fully finished, which is not what I want.

### Part 2

Getting into more details: Imagine `my_command` is actually a command that connects my shell to a remote shell. Would this change in any way our solution to **Part 1**?

In case the details matter, `my_command` is actually a one-line command:

`bsub /bin/zsh`.

This is a [`Platform LSF`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_LSF) command that submits a job from a login machine (an interactive zsh shell in our case) to a remote grid. Once the submited job gets an open slot on the grid, LSF dispatches it, giving me an interactive shell on the remote machine.

The first thing `bsub` does is output the `job ID` of my job on the remote queue (this is what I hope to parse in my script), and then once a slot is open, it dispatches my job.

I'm wondering if a trivial solution to  **Part 1** would work for **Part 2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `read` to get one line of input at a time. You can do something like this:

```
my_command | { 
  read line
  line=$(grep -oEe '[0-9]+');
  if [ $line ]; then
    echo 'Here is the first line ' $line
  fi
  #possibly read more from my_command, transfer control to another program via `exec`, etc...
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just pipe to head -1?

```
# Get a code that `my_command` prints in its first line
# parsed_first_line=`my_command | grep -oEe '[0-9]+'`
parsed_first_line=$( my_command | head -1 | grep -oEe '[0-9]+' )
echo 'Here is the first line ' $parsed_first_line
```

This also lets my_command finish, but it only brings back the first line, which it can then match against your grep.

Answer (score 1):

This is for `bash`, `zsh` may be a bit different:

```
#!/bin/bash

# We'll need a temporary file.
TMPFILE=`mktemp`

# Start the process in the background
my_command > $TMPFILE &

# Get its pid so we can clean up that temp file later.
PID=$!

# Wait for the first line of output
first_line=`head -n1 $TMPFILE | grep -oEe '[0-9]+'`
while [ -z "$first_line" ]; do 
    # Don't technically need this, but it'll prevent the system from grinding.
    sleep 1
    first_line=`head -n1 $TMPFILE | grep -oEe '[0-9]+'`
done

echo Result: "$first_line"

# Clean up that temp file.
wait $PID
rm $TMPFILE
```